# GitLab does not update certain links after changing the server's hostname

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

I installed GitLab on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS server using the command found in [the documentation](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1404)

`curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce`

Everything installed correctly and the application is running but I changed the hostname on the server by editing `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` but certain parts of GitLab like the repository URL incorrectly display the old hostname. How do I fix this?

I found some references around the web to using bitnami to reconfigure this but I didn't seem to have the same files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that kind of thing, it's best to go through the gitlab reconfiguration step mentioned in that documentation:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

That should update things. But before you do that, you will need to check the gitlab config files in `/etc/gitlab` (I believe) to make sure the old hostname wasn't put in there.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had to change `external_url` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and then run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.